# Searching using FieldValues is not working on OData

Tags: odata

I have followed the docs and none of these worked:

```
?$filter=FieldValues/Product_Name eq 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
and
?$filter=contains(FieldValues/Product_Name,'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

However when I searched using `?$filter=Name eq 'Item Name'` then it generated a result.

Is there anything that I've missed here? Perhaps a configuration? I have done rebuilding my search index and populated my schema but still to no avail.

EDIT: I'm using Sitecore 9.0.2

Comment: What version of Sitecore do you have?

Comment: @x3mxray I'm using 9.0.2

Comment: FieldValues property should work in 9.0.2 according official documentation, but I`m not sure (earlier versions have property "Fields" instead of "FieldValues"). You can easy check it (for example by querying "$expand=FieldValues" and "$expand=Fields").

Comment: @x3mxray I may have found the root cause, now. Well actually I was using a multilist as one of my search criteria, and it turns out dashes could have been treated as a space so the GUID XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX is treated as  XXXXXXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX (which will result to nothing), is there a way that I can improve this?

Comment: OData has special `guid` keyword. Try this one: $filter=FieldValues/Product_Name eq  (guid'" + yourId + "'). Query should be like: $filter=FieldValues/Product_Name eq  (guid'D37A2617-1AB6-48C6-BB5A-0582395DD622')

Comment: @x3mxray This error popped up: Unrecognized 'Edm.String' literal 'guid'3d9e15a7-f5b1-49b5-ad54-471f1df7427b''

Comment: @x3mxray I can just go ahead and use it directly: $filter=FieldValues/Product_Name eq D37A2617-1AB6-48C6-BB5A-0582395DD622 , this works now. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, yes. `guid` keyword was removed in OData v4 and later. Try query without quotes: `?$filter=FieldValues/Product_Name eq XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`. http://blog.simpletrees.com/2015/12/web-api-preview-unrecognized-edmstring.html

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes and use this syntax

```
?$filter=FieldValues/Product_Name eq 3d9e15a7-f5b1-49b5-ad54-471f1df7427b
```

(guid must be on lowercase)